# Angularjs angular-ui-switch adding an additional ng-change event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add an additional ng-change event attribute to this directive:

```
angular.module('uiSwitch', [])

.directive('switch', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE'
        , replace: true
        , transclude: true
        , template: function(element, attrs) {
            var html = '';
            html += '<span';
            html +=   ' class="switch' + (attrs.class ? ' ' + attrs.class : '') + '"';
            html +=   attrs.ngModel ? ' ng-click="' + attrs.ngModel + '=!' + attrs.ngModel + '"' : '';
            html +=   ' ng-class="{ checked:' + attrs.ngModel + ' }"';
            html +=   '>';
            html +=   '<small></small>';
            html +=   '<input type="checkbox"';
            html +=     attrs.id ? ' id="' + attrs.id + '"' : '';
            html +=     attrs.name ? ' name="' + attrs.name + '"' : '';
            html +=     attrs.ngModel ? ' ng-model="' + attrs.ngModel + '"' : '';
            html +=     attrs.ngChange ? ' ng-change="' + attrs.ngChange + '"' : '';
            html +=     ' style="display:none" />';
            html += '</span>';
            return html;
        }
    }
})
```

I added the following line:

```
html +=     attrs.ngChange ? ' ng-change="' + attrs.ngChange + '"' : '';
```

But when I pass a function to be called when implementing the directive, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
<switch id="question" name="question" ng-model="questionAnswered" ng-chnage="myFunction()" class="green"></switch>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the **name** of your function, instead of calling it by the `()`, like this:

```
<switch id="question" name="question" ng-model="questionAnswered" ng-change="myFunction" class="green"></switch>
```

Comment: Yes, I had a syntax problem but yeah it worked thanks

Comment: @Joofville glad to help, vote up the answer then if it helped! ;)

Comment: Could you tell what was the problem? I think I'm having the same problem!

Comment: The problem is that you have to pass your function by name and not by calling it, that is, without parenthesis.

Comment: I've created my own directive based on this one that allows for a three way switch: true, false and null.